# Next.js Environment variables work locally but not when hosted on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, next.js

Have a Next.js project.

This is my next.config.js file, which I followed through with on this guide: https://dev.to/tesh254/environment-variables-from-env-file-in-nextjs-570b

```
module.exports = withCSS(withSass({
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins = config.plugins || []
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: ['@svgr/webpack',  {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 100000,
                name: '[name].[ext]'
            }}],
        });

        config.plugins = [
          ...config.plugins,

          // Read the .env file
          new Dotenv({
            path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
            systemvars: true
          })
        ]

        const env = Object.keys(process.env).reduce((acc, curr) => {
          acc[`process.env.${curr}`] = JSON.stringify(process.env[curr]);
          return acc;
        }, {});
        // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
        config.node = {
          fs: 'empty'
        }

         /** Allows you to create global constants which can be configured
        * at compile time, which in our case is our environment variables
        */
        config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

        return config
      }
    }),

    );
```

I have a .env file which holds the values I need. It works when run on localhost.

In my Kubernetes environment, within the deploy file which I can modify, I have the same environment variables set up. But when I try and identify them they come off as undefined, so my application cannot run.

I refer to it like:

```
process.env.SOME_VARIABLE
```

which works locally.

Does anyone have experience making environment variables function on Next.js when deployed? Not as simple as it is for a backend service. :(

**EDIT:**
This is what the environment variable section looks like.

**EDIT 2:**
Full deploy file, edited to remove some details

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "38"
  creationTimestamp: xx
  generation: 40
  labels:
    app: appname
  name: appname
  namespace: development
  resourceVersion: xx
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/development/deployments/appname
  uid: xxx
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: xx
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: appname
      tier: sometier
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: appname
        tier: sometier
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: development
        - name: PORT
          value: "3000"
        - name: SOME_VAR
          value: xxx
        - name: SOME_VAR
          value: xxxx
        image: someimage
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: appname
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 3000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: xxx
    lastUpdateTime: xxxx
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 40
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Comment: Where is the .env file located in your project? Also, might be worth to look into the permissions for that file.

Comment: The .env exists in the root directory, alongside package.json etc. (Outside of the /src dir)

Comment: For Kubernetes, I do "kubectl edit deploy project_name" and it allows me to modify the config of the deployed product, and also add environment variables as I have. This method works for backend services but the browser stuff is different.

Comment: can you please share your deployment file ?

Comment: I've added an example of the environment variable section to OP

Answer (score 3):

.env Works in docker or docker-compose, they do not work in Kubernetes, if you want to add them you can by configmaps objects or add directly to each deployment an example (from documentation):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow
```

Also, the best and standard way is to use config maps, for example:

```
  containers:
    - env:
        - name: DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE
              name: darwined-env
```

And the config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  DB_DEFAULT_DATABASE: darwined_darwin_dev_1
 kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: darwin-env
  name: darwined-env
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have this sort of setup when I edit the deploy of the pod. Do I need to have them added in the deploy.yaml, or the current way of editing it through "kubectl edit deploy service-name" is the same thing?

Comment: Both work, but it's better to use config maps as the late example shows

Comment: My issue is that I have the setup you suggested, but it doesn't work when actually deployed. Locally it works fine but when deployed onto a pod the process.env.SOME_VAR returns an undefined.

Comment: Please post your full deployment file

Comment: I've added the current file to the OP. Edited out project specific details cus NDA etc.

Comment: Okay if you kubectl exec -ti <pod-name> bash, and then do a env | grep NODE_ENV

Comment: PS C:\Users\xxx> kubectl exec -ti podname bash

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126

Comment: in podname you should put your pod name

Comment: I did haha, I am just removing the actual name so there's no reference to the project details

Comment: does that container has bash? or can you run the comand 
kubectl exec <podname> 'env | grep NODE_ENV'

Comment: I get the following error when running that command:
 "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"env | grep NODE_ENV\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
command terminated with exit code 126"

Comment: well as i cannot help much without knowing what commands could be run inside the container, try to get inside and check if the environment  vars are getting passed

Comment: When run locally the application reads the .env file and the environment variables are read. When deployed it doesn't detect them for some reason. I have them set up like I do with my other services (which are backend, so don't require the same configurations as a Next.js app does). The environment variables in the deploy file are set correctly. I'm just not understanding why the pod doesn't use them / recognize them. Do you have a similar set up?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to help you here with, thing is check how to run commands inside the docker container of next.js to check if the variables are being passed inside, else you have a problem in the YAML descriptor of the deployment

Comment: Ok I accessed the container and did a printenv which gave me a ton of environment variables, including the ones I have set myself.

Comment: Then your problem is in the code inside the container and not passing the variables to the container :)

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. My question is how to access these variables from the Next.js application? It works client side no problem, but why can't I access the environment variables in the container?

Comment: Oh now I see the problem, my bad, so you are reading the .env file in the code! 
and now there is no env file in your container. So either make sure the .env file is getting inside the container, or change the code to read from environment variables and not .env file

Comment: When reading an environment variable on a backend Node.js service for example, reading from an .env file is the equivalent to reading from the container environment variables. This I understand is not the same case on a frontend service. When running locally I need to read from an .env file, when running when deployed I need to read from the environment variables. The code must remain the same for it to work across both domains. If I have to change the code depending on where I'm running the application it defeats the point of environment variables.

Comment: Nope, when you run containers with docker-compose, the variables in the .env file are read as environment variables, the thing is you were  reading from the file if you change the code to only read from environment variables will work in both

Comment: What kind of code do I write to not read from the .env file and read only from environment variables? I'm confused

Comment: with this code, you are reading the env file:
          // Read the .env file
          new Dotenv({
            path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
            systemvars: true
          })
        ]
instead just access the variables with process.env.MY_VAR